# Como sumar atributos de un objeto tipo number a una fecha

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bucle-for, momentjs

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente objeto:

```
const disp = [{"uuid":902384, "start": "4:00", "stations":[{"uuid":123214, "seq":1, "time":1}]}]
```

Requiero tomar la hora y minutos del atributo start y sumarselos por el atributo de stations.time
1 se multiplica por 10, porque aplica a 10 minutos. He estado intentadolo con la libreria momentjs, pero no me deja entonces, queria saber como lo haria ustedes.

Aqui el codigo

```
for (const i in disp) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(disp, i)) {
      let hour = moment().format(disp[i].start, 'hh:mm')
      console.log(hour)
      let minutes = 0
      console.log(disp[i].uuid)
      disp[i]['stations'].forEach(element => {
          if (element.numberOfOrders !== null) {
            minutes = minutes+element.time * 10
          }
      });
      console.log(minutes)
      let timeAll = moment(hour).add(minutes, 'minutes')
      console.log(timeAll)
  }
}
```

Consigo el resultado de objeto multiplicado por 10, pero a la hora de instanciar el moment.add o en este caso hour.add, para sumarle los minutos a la hora de inicio. me arroja .add() is not a function

Agradecido con sus comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `hour` no es un objeto moment, sino un string. Esto es porque estas usando `format` en vez de parsear la hora.

Para solucionarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const disp = [{"uuid":902384, "start": "4:00", "stations":[{"uuid":123214, "seq":1, "time":1}]}];

for (const i in disp) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(disp, i)) {
      let hour = moment(disp[i].start, 'hh:mm') // Acá debes usas el constructor de moment en vez de `format`
      console.log("hour: ", hour)
      let minutes = 0;
      disp[i]['stations'].forEach(element => {
          if (element.numberOfOrders !== null) {
            minutes = minutes+element.time * 10;
          }
      });
      console.log("minutes: ", minutes)
      let timeAll = moment(hour).add(minutes, 'minutes') // Acá ya no hay problemas en usar add()
      console.log("timeAll: ", timeAll)
      console.log("timeAll Hours: ", timeAll.hour())
      console.log("timeAll Minutes: ", timeAll.minute())
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```